# Can Discord automatically unfurl links from bots? If so, how?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

Discord seems to be quite good (if a bit capricious) about unfurling links that a user posts in a channel, and also seems to be quite keen to support developers writing bots that act much like helpful users.

It's a bit weird then that it doesn't seem possible for links posted by bots to be unfurled in the same way.

I'm using *this library* https://github.com/andrejbauer/slack-to-discord to copy over channels from a free Slack instance we are abandoning in favor of Discord, but wish there was some way for unfurling to be done on the links users have previously posted. As far as I can see this is a historical shortcoming, Discord isn't interested in this working and there questions stretching back years and no answers.

The closest I can see is individual users attempting to do the unfurl links for their bots themselves, but that's really not a great choice and highly fragile IMHO.

Thanks if you have any clues for me to follow or I've somehow misjudged the current state of play and you have better information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe discord supports stuff like that, and of course it's a pain to do anything manually, but I don't think it's possible to do this yet.

Comment: And yet, if a user types a URL in a channel it unfurls automatically. Seems like a weird design oversight.

Comment: As I did say, I'm not 100% sure, but I use discord and code my own bots, and I don't think it works like that